# Build a jenkins job from a git repo subdirectory

Tags: git, github, jenkins

My git repo (repo.git) has 2 folders (mod1 and mod2) in the same branch. These are mainly database objects but for different modules. I need to have 2 jobs on Jenkins to build for mod1 and mod2. The build will be set up to be a "build with parameters" where in I can specify the module to be built. The source git repo branch will be mentioned in the configuration. How can I specify the folder (mod1 or mod2) as a parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [string paramter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)

and than cd to your relevant folder and build ..